# Access each column from csv file in unix scripting using a for loop

Tags: unix, for-loop, awk, scripting

I want to know the syntax of accessing each column individually (f1,f2,f3) while reading a csv file using a for loop

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
```

I cannot use the while format as I am writing the above code in a "awk" command and the file name is specified later on. Kindly let me know how to modify the above code to access each column individually as I need to access it inside an if statement.

The above code is accessing the whole row. For example; -

```
Keys,YES,565 
Adam,NO,980 
Shannon,YES,980
```

I want to access the second column and use it to put an if condition inside an awk. if($f2="NO") . Can this also be done using the above code?

It is to replace the below part of code to make output as an html file

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
printf "<TD>%s</TD>", $i
print "</TR>" }
```

Comment: Well, that's the code to _access each column individually_. Other than that, you need to be more specific on your needs.

Comment: The above code is accessing the whole row. For example; -    
Keys,YES,565    
Adam,NO,980     
Shannon,YES,980

I want to access the second column and use it to put an if condition inside an awk. if($f2="NO") . Can this also be done using the above code?

Comment: Please, just show your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is very vague, I can only guess at an answer. You need to use the appropriate field separator:

```
awk -F',' '{ print $2 }' some_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Try code like this.

```
CSV_FILE=a.csv
DATA=$(cat ${CSV_FILE})
for line in $DATA ;do
    ELEMENT=`echo $line | awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $3}'`
    echo $ELEMENT
    ##You have your if condition here##
done
```